# How to modify an arbitrary case class (e.g., replace the first field) using its generic representation in Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to write a function that given an arbitrary case class replaces the value of the first field with the given new value, using Shapeless.

So far I have the following:

```
  def replaceHead[T, H, R >: H :: HList](obj: T, newHead: H)(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[T, R]): T =
    generic.to(obj) match {
      case h :: t => generic.from(newHead :: t)
    }
```

If I don't put any type restrictions on `R`, I cannot use `generic.from(newHead :: t)` because it understandably expects a subtype of `R`. If I put `R >: H :: HList`, I get the following error:

```
Error:(19, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter generic: shapeless.Generic.Aux[Test.Record,String :: shapeless.HList]
  println(replaceHead(Record("abc", 123), "def"))
```

The only way that I could get it to "work" is with an ugly hack like this that is not type safe:

```
  def replaceHead[T, H, R](obj: T, newHead: H)(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[T, R]): T =
    generic.to(obj) match {
      case h :: t => generic.from((newHead :: t).asInstanceOf[R])
    }

  replaceHead(Record("abc", 123), "def") // Works
  replaceHead(Record("abc", 123), 456) // Crashes at runtime
```

I understand that the root problem is because `R` ends up being for instance `String :: Int :: HNil` which *is* `String :: HList` but `String :: HList` is not necessarily `String :: Int :: HNil`, but I can't find a way to access the head of the generic representation without erasing the type signature of the tail.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick,

```
def replaceHead[C, R <: HList, H, T <: HList](c: C, newHead: H)
  (implicit
     gen: Generic.Aux[C, R],
     ev1: (H :: T) =:= R,
     ev2: R =:= (H :: T)
  ): C = gen.from(newHead :: gen.to(c).tail)

scala> replaceHead(Foo(23, "foo"), 13)
res0: Foo = Foo(13,foo)
```

We need to two type equalities to prove that the representation type `R` is same as `H :: T` in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and one I'm not convinced I've found the simplest solution for. But this does work:

```
trait NonEmptyHList[T, Head] {
  def replaceHead(t: T, h: Head): T
}

implicit def nonEmptyHList[H, Rest <: HList]: NonEmptyHList[H :: Rest, H] = new NonEmptyHList[H :: Rest, H] {
  def replaceHead(t: H :: Rest, h: H): H :: Rest = t match {
    case _ :: rest => h :: rest
  }
}

def replaceHead[T, H, R](obj: T, h: H)(implicit generic: Generic.Aux[T, R], nonEmpty: NonEmptyHList[R, H]): T = {
  generic.from(nonEmpty.replaceHead(generic.to(obj), h))
}

val rec = new Record("hello", 1)
replaceHead(rec, "hi")  // Record("hi", 1)
replaceHead(rec, 2)  // compile error
```